# attributedString and textView color change in a for loop

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

I used `attributedString` to change the color of a part of the text in the textView. The problem is that it only changes the color of the first string that it finds and It's case sensitive. I want it to change the color of all same strings in the text. Anyone knows how to write a loop for it?
Here is my code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var textView: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var textBox: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let text = "Love ,love, love, love, Love"
        let linkTextWithColor = "love"        
        let range = (text as NSString).rangeOfString(linkTextWithColor)

        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:text)
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.redColor() , range: range)

        self.textView.attributedText = attributedString
    } 
}
```

It only changes the first "**love**" that it finds.

Here is the output:

[image: Example output]

Comment: So do you want whole string's color as red? or do you want red color on `love` where `L` is lowercase letter? or anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let s = "love, Love, lOVE, LOVE"

let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "love", options: .CaseInsensitive)

let matches = regex.matchesInString(s, options: .WithoutAnchoringBounds, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: s.utf16.count))

let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: s)

for m in matches {
    attributedString.addAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor()], range: m.range)
}
```

Comment: NSRegularExpression uses UTF-16 based range, `s.characters.count` should be `s.utf16.count`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `NSRegularExpression`, but if you prefer `rangeOfString` method, you can write something like this:

```
let text = "Love ,love, love, love, Love"
let linkTextWithColor = "love"

var startLocation = 0
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:text)
while case let range = (text as NSString).rangeOfString(linkTextWithColor,
                                                        options: [.CaseInsensitiveSearch],
                                                        range: NSRange(startLocation..<text.utf16.count))
    where range.location != NSNotFound
{
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                  value: UIColor.redColor(),
                                  range: range)
    startLocation += range.length
}
```